# ¿Por qué Python me da errores al instalar librerías?

Tags: python

Cuando intento instalar librerías en Python me dice que no encuentra el paquete o que no cuento con la version, aún cuando tengo actualizado Python y `pip`.

[image: Tengo Python y pip en versiones recientes]

Comment: ¿Probaste indicándole la versión?. Desconozco que versión quieras usar pero por ejemplo: pip install pyqt==1.0

Comment: si, y me sigue dando el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Y debe funcionar. Considera ejecutar `cmd.exe` como administrador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias hermano, lo hice así y funcionó

Comment: Un placer ayudar. Buena suerte!

Comment: y con la librería tkinter, como puedo hacer?

Comment: tkinter viene por defecto en la mayoría de las instalaciones de python, sobre todo si estas en windows. Probaste importarla?

Comment: aun no lo he intentado, pero lo haré, nuevamente muchas gracias pcr la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que la librería que quieras instalar es compatible con la versión de Python que estés usando, puedes conseguir esa información buscando la librería en [www.pypi.org](http://www.pypi.org). También hay ocasiones en que las librerías necesitan tener instalados ciertos recursos en tu equipo.
Deberías compartir el error o errores que arroja Python.